# Why some regular expressions are not working with java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: regex, kotlin

Currently I am working on one of the BLE communication-related app, Where BLE device sending data in JSON format. I have one requirement to make sure that received data should be in JSON format before passing to the caller method.

So, I have created one JSON Validator which is going to validate received response should have expected field name and JSON Object and Array symbols. Here is JSONValidator Kotlin code which is testing JSON Object and Array symbol in response.

```
class JSONValidator: StringValidator() {

  private val jsonArray = "(^\\[|]\$)"
  private val jsonObject = "([{}])"
  private val jsonArrayAndObject = "(^\\[\\{|}]\$)"

  override fun isStringValid(s: String?): Boolean {
        return if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {
            false
        } else {
            doesPacketContainJson(s)
        }
    }

  private fun doesPacketContainJson(s: String): Boolean {
        return Regex(jsonObject).containsMatchIn(s) ||
               Regex(jsonArray).containsMatchIn(s) ||
               Regex(jsonArrayAndObject).containsMatchIn(s)
    }
}
```

JSONValidator Test Class

```
class JSONValidatorTest {

    private val packetValidator: StringValidator = JSONValidator()

    // Other Test cases

    @Test
    fun `validate contains json`() {
        val partialJson1 = "{"
        val partialJson2 = "}"
        val partialJson3 = "[{"
        val partialJson4 = "]}"
        val partialJson5 = "]"

        //Issue: These test cases always failed
        assert(packetValidator.isStringValid(partialJson1))
        assert(packetValidator.isStringValid(partialJson2))
        assert(packetValidator.isStringValid(partialJson3))
        assert(packetValidator.isStringValid(partialJson4))
        assert(packetValidator.isStringValid(partialJson5))
    }
}
```

I have cross verified Regular expression on below sites and It's working fine over there. I hope I am doing things right. :

- https://regex101.com/
- https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

I did google but unable to find any help around my use-case. Can anyone have any experience or idea around this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what are you trying to match with the patterns? Why not use Kotlin regex API?

Comment: And more importantly, why don't you ask one of the zilions JSON parsers to parse and thus valdate the JSON instead of trying to use regexps?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have just updated to use Kotlin regular expression but the same result. I want to just make sure the response string should only have JSON specific symbols and field as per expectation.

Comment: @JBNizet I can validate JSON with native org.json package exception but App will mostly receive partial JSON which I can validate based on the JSON symbol and expected fields. I know this is still not full-proof, But though something is better than nothing.

Comment: When I copy & paste your code the test just works as is